# AC current measurement with ACS712 and Python

Tags: python, pi-2

I'm currently trying to program my ACS712 5a current sensor to my Raspberry Pi.
At the moment I have hooked up my current sensor via ADC (ADS1115) to the Raspberry Pi 4. ADC seems to read the quiescent current of Vcc/5 = 2.5V and seems to increase whenever I atleast trying with DC current but not much happens with AC current from my signal generator. All the code is written in Python.

Is there any calculations I have missed on?

```
While True:

  Vcc = 5.0
  sense = 0.185 #from datasheet, 66 to 185mV/A
  QOV = Vcc/2 #quiesent voltage
  ADC_Voltage = adcIn #Seperate method from ADC code
  voltage_raw = (5.0 / 65535) * ADC_Voltage #65536 because I got 16 bit ADC
  voltage = voltage_raw - QOV
  current = voltage/sense   
  return current
```

I also send the code for the ADC,

```
RATE = 860 #SPS rate
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
ads = ADS.ADS1115(i2c)
ads.data_rate = RATE
chan = AnalogIn(ads, ADS.P0)
voltage = chan.voltage
return voltage
```

My main goal is to try to get a decent sinus represenation using Matplotlib to visualize the current. I attached a picture of how to visualization is looking the moment and the ADC printing out the ADC value and the voltage, (this shows the quiescent voltage, no current applied). When I applied current (about 2A, the raw increases to about 23000 and voltage to 2.92V).

Hopefully I have provided enought information about my issue.

[image]

Comment: Please show us the code that is communicating with your shell/console. What is the baud rate? Can you fix the graph so the x axis tics are readable?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The baud rate is the default rate, not sure how im going to change it. Ive also updated the picture in the thread. Not sure what you mean about the shell/console, im kinda new to this.